# Screenshot from a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios4

I know there are many questions about this theme but I really read all of them but
not found an answer.

I want make a screenshot from the current table view. and i do it this way:

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromCurrentView
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.tableView.bounds.size, YES, 1);
    [self.tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Everything works fine, but when i scroll down in the tableview and make the screenshot,
half of the image is black. I don't know how to make the screenshot from the actual 
tableview area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because UITableViewCell is reusable, when scrolling the table view, the cells outside the view ports will be enqueued for reusing and removed from the table view. So try to keep the cells only be reusable on its index path:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell_%d_%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row]; 
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }
  ...
  return cell;
}
```

Not tested yet, give it a try. Yes, this will consume much more memory, do it with screenshot purpose only.

Edit: if you care the memory usage, may be you can take screenshot of current view port, then programmatically scroll top and down to take other parts of screenshots, and combine all the screen shots at last.

Comment: thx for the answer. I am not realy sure wath you mean with "do it with screenshot purpose only". Now i have a button which make the screenshot. What i have to do whit this code when i push the screenshot button without consume more memory?

Comment: On normal ways, the number of cells only a litter more or equal to the view port can contain, they are reusable when scrolling the table view, so it can run smoothly even if it contains a large amount items. On my way here, the number of cells is the same as the number of all the rows of table view, so if your table view has a large amount items, it will eat lots of memory than normal way. So be care. If you consider the memory usage as first, don't use this method, although it can work.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, and this didn't solve it for me. @Missaq did this solve the problem for you?

Comment: Hi, I know this is a little bit outdated, but for anyone else searching for this you can take a look at this library: https://github.com/davidman/DHSmartScreenshot

Answer (score 24):

This will get you the current visible region of the TableView.

If you want to render the entire tableview, first you need to be aware thats probably not a great idea for anything more than a few dozen rows because of memory and what not.  The max image size in 2048x2048 so your tableView can be no taller than that.

```
UIView *viewToRender = self.tableView;
CGPoint contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToRender.bounds.size);

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//  KEY: need to translate the context down to the current visible portion of the tablview
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -contentOffset.y);

[viewToRender.layer renderInContext:ctx];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, at least it fixed it for me. 

 CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, -contentOffset.y);

Comment: This answers my question of how to take a screenshot of a scrolled UIScrollView (UITableView or other).  When taking a screenshot of a scrollview that had been scrolled I got black bars the size of my scrolled offset.  So thank you, thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 22):

take a look at this [library](https://github.com/davidman/DHSmartScreenshot) I made to do exactly this, it has very useful methods like:

1. Take a full screenshot of your UITableView (all the cells are rendered on a single UIImage)
2. Take a screenshot for just a single cell given its indexPath
3. Take a screenshot of just the headers, footers or rows of your UITableView

And more...

You can add it to your project via Cocoapods or manually by dragging the Source files.

The usage is so simple:

```
UIImage * tableViewScreenshot = [self.tableView screenshot];
```

I hope you find this library helpful as much as I do.

Comment: The most exciting library I've seen so far :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The following code works perfect in my application , you can use this code to capture screenshot of tableview or any other scrollview that has horizontal scrolling

```
CGPoint offset = [_tableView contentOffset];
_tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);

CGRect visibleRect = _tableView.bounds;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_tableView.contentSize, _tableView.opaque, 0.0);

[_tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

while (_tipsTableView.contentSize.height>= (visibleRect.origin.y+visibleRect.size.height)) {

    visibleRect.origin.y += visibleRect.size.height;

    [_tableView scrollRectToVisible:visibleRect animated:NO];
    [_tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
}

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();   

_tableView.contentOffset = offset;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)cellTobeCaptured isImage:(BOOL)isImage
{

//If UITableViewCell contains UIImageView

    if(isImage){
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cellTobeCaptured.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
     [cellTobeCaptured drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, cellTobeCaptured.bounds.size.width, cellTobeCaptured.bounds.size.height) afterScreenUpdates:NO];
     UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     return image;
    }
else{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cellTobeCaptured.bounds.size, cellTobeCaptured.opaque, 0.0);
  [cellTobeCaptured.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
   UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   return img;
   }
}
```

=> Call the method as

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:arrIndex inSection:0]];
 self->screenShotImage = [self imageWithView:cell isImage:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to replicate the Apple calendar scrolling when changing months in my own custom calendar built using a UITableView. After calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath:, making sure that animated: is YES so that scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation: is called, in scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation: I called reloadData: on the tableView before the renderInContext:. The full tableview was then rendered to the image. I ended up not using this in the long run so not sure of the reliability of it as a permanent solution but it worked well when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5 you can use this code

```
    let viewToRender = tableView;
    let contentOffset = tableView.contentOffset

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToRender.bounds.size)

    if let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
       ctx.translateBy(x: 0, y: -contentOffset.y)

       viewToRender.layer.render(in: ctx)

       let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```