# Print UITableView that has content off screen?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, printing

Hi I have an iOS app that has the ability to print a UITableView. However, only th part of the tableview that is shown is printed. Is there a way to print the whole tableview, even if it has not been drawn yet?

Here is the code I am using to print:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainTableView.contentSize);
[self.mainTableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIPrintInteractionController *printer = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
printer.printingItem = viewImage;
UIPrintInfo *info = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printer.printInfo = info;
UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler =
^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    if (!completed && error)
        NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u: %@",
              error.domain, error.code, [error localizedDescription]);
}; 
UIButton * printButton = (UIButton *)sender;
if(UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad == [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]){
    [printer presentFromRect:printButton.frame inView:self.view animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
} else {
    [printer presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many discussions about this problem. Two examples:

[SO: Screenshot from a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402393/screenshot-from-a-uitableview)

[SO: How to take an iPhone screenshot of entire view including parts off screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328201/how-to-take-an-iphone-screenshot-of-entire-view-including-parts-off-screen)

The problem is, that UITableViews reuse their cells.
I think the most common approaches are:

1. Scroll programmatically to different parts of your UITableView, take the different screenshots and merge them together again.
2. Resize the UITableView so its that big that all cells fit into it. WARNING: This quickly leads to memory issues (No cell reuse any longer), so just do it for screenshot purposes and if your cell count is not that big.